# Merging Two Pandas Dataframes Around the Intersection of the Data From Two Columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, machine-learning

I have two data frames I'm working with. The first, `d1`...

```
+-------+----------+-------------+-------+
| Index | Location | Num of Reps | Sales |
+-------+----------+-------------+-------+
|     0 |    75894 |           3 |    12 |
|     1 |    75286 |           7 |    24 |
|     2 |    27659 |           3 |    17 |
|     3 |    38482 |           6 |    19 |
|     4 |    78634 |           8 |    21 |
+-------+----------+-------------+-------+
```

and the second `d2`

```
+-------+--------+
| Index | Profit |
+-------+--------+
| 27654 | 132.65 |
| 75894 | 140.38 |
| 75286 | 310.28 |
| 38482 | 290.83 |
| 75894 | 156.78 |
| 86753 | 302.35 |
+-------+--------+
```

In d2, the location values are listed as the index. d2 has more rows than the d1 and only a subset of the location values from d2 match up with those from d1.

What I would like, is a new dataframe (`d3`) that contains the intersection of location values, with all of the column data from both dataframes if there is match. In this example, it would look like...

```
+-------+----------+-------------+-------+--------+
| Index | Location | Num of Reps | Sales | Profit |
+-------+----------+-------------+-------+--------+
|     0 |    75894 |           3 |    12 | 140.38 |
|     1 |    75286 |           7 |    24 | 310.28 |
|     2 |    38482 |           6 |    19 | 290.83 |
+-------+----------+-------------+-------+--------+
```

Here's what I am thinking of code-wise:

```
d2['Location'] = d2(0, axis=1)
d2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
d3 = d1
#d3['Profit'] = <missing code>
```

For the line that is commented out, I am thinking perhaps some sort of lambda function that would check for a matching zip code and append the correlated value in case of a match. But I'm not sure it can all be done in a single line.

The first line of the above code throws the following error:

```
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

Comment: `d1.merge(d2.rename(columns={"Index": "Location"}))`

Comment: @Psidom, that line of code results in the following ``MergeError: No common columns to perform merge on``

Comment: You need a `Location` column in `d1` to work correctly, which I assume you have from your example data.

Comment: Yes there is a ``Location`` column in ``d1``, the error message remains the same.

Comment: Why don't you have both of the results corresponding to Location 75894 in your desired output?

Comment: Maybe the `Index` in `d2` is actual index then? I assume it's a column which looks like the case from what you've posted.

Comment: @Psidom If an index, then I would think just `d1.merge(d2, left_on='Location', right_index=True)`, but then you would of course have two results for Location 75894.

Comment: Yes, @Psidom, it's the actual index, which happens to be populated with location data.